# AutoLayout SubViews alignment to superview's center X

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

[image]

How does subviews alignment to superview's center X?

I have two subviews is added to resizing able superview.
The subviewA want to trailing alignment to superview's center X and 
The subviewB want to leading to superview's center X.

As this situation How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the constraints with the following patterns ([NSLayoutConstraint class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html)):

```
[superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subviewA 
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing 
               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                  toItem:superview 
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
              multiplier:1.0 
                constant:0.0]];

[superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subviewB 
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading 
               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                  toItem:superview 
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
              multiplier:1.0 
                constant:0.0]];
```